# Cannot creating Session Beans in Netbeans 11.1

Tags: netbeans, dependencies, ejb, stateless-session-bean

My goal is to work with (stateless) session beans in NetBeans 11.1.
I'm working on the OS Ubuntu-Mate 18 and I'm using the GlassFish 5.1.0 server.

I tried to implement a session bean like in the tutorials https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/SessionBean/SessionBeanDemo.html. Unfortunately, most of the tutorials are old and deprecated. I'd tried to implement a stateless session bean as follows:

First, I started a new "Enterprise Application" project.

[image]

Then I choosed a name...

[image]

... and I leaved the check marks on creating EJB and Web App module.

[image]

After that the Ear-Folder showed a strange warning about the dependency artifacts. If I try to resolve the project problems, nothing happend.

You can read the description in the screenshot.

[image]

When I began to create a session bean in SessionTest-ejb-1.0 I'm not able to choose a location.
The EJB-Module is supposed to make the session bean work.

[image]

I don't have any idea how to implement a session bean in Netbean 11.1. I can't rely on the internet tutorials. Netbeans 11.1 is completely different than the other versions.

Comment: [1] What JDK version are you using, since as far as I know, GlassFish 5 does not support any JDK > 8. [2] If possible, [upgrade to NetBeans 11.2](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb112/nb112.html) to see if the problem persists. [3] Can you update your question to show the output from the build?

Comment: Try manually building the projects **session-test-ejb-1.0** and **session-test-war-1.0** first: select each project, then right-click and select **Clean and Build** from the context menu. And once those projects have built successfully, try building 
**session-test-ear-1.0**. Does that resolve your _"strange warning"_?

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same problem persists using netbeans 11.2 and the wildfly server.

I think the problem is in the ejb plugin of netbeans 11.x

To solve the problem, I created the Entreprise Application using Netbeans 9.0 (it works), then I opened it using the latest version of Netbeans 11.2.